# Julia: Append to an array

Tags: julia

Someone please help me understand this.  I have the following code below.  I am trying to append `index[i]-1` to an empty array. However I am getting this error: "`BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{Any,1} at index [1]`" :

```
sample_size_array = [9,5,6,9,2,6,9]
n_minus_1 = []
array_length = length(sample_size_array)
for i in 1:array_length
    n_minus_1[i].append(sample_size_array[i] -1)
end
println(n_minus_1)
```

If Julia does not understand `array[0]` then why is i starting at 0 and not at 1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

- in the first iteration you are trying to access `n_minus_1` array at index `1` while this array is still empty (has `0` length) - this throws you an error;
- in Julia you do not invoke methods using a `.` (this symbol is used for different purposes - in this case it is parsed as field access and also would throw an error later)

To solve both those problems use `push!` function which appends an element at the end of an array. The code could look like this:

```
sample_size_array = [9,5,6,9,2,6,9]
n_minus_1 = []
array_length = length(sample_size_array)
for i in 1:array_length
    push!(n_minus_1, sample_size_array[i]-1)
end
println(n_minus_1)
```

However in this case the whole operation can be written even simpler as:

```
n_minus_1 = sample_size_array .- 1
```

and you do not need any loop (and here you see another use of `.` in Julia - in this case we use it to signal that we want to subtract `1` from every element of `sample_size_array`).